# Generic Avro Deserializer for Flink : override getProducedType

Tags: scala, deserialization, apache-flink, avro

I would like to create a Generic Avro Deserializer and use it with Kafka/Flink.

To do that I have to extend DeserializationSchema from Flink API :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

import com.sksamuel.avro4s.{AvroInputStream, FromRecord, SchemaFor, ToRecord}
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor

class MyGenericAvroDeserializer[T](implicit schema: SchemaFor[T], toRecord: ToRecord[T], fromRecord: FromRecord[T])
  extends DeserializationSchema[T] {

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: T): Boolean = false

  override def deserialize(message: Array[Byte]): T = {
    AvroInputStream.binary[T](new ByteArrayInputStream(message)).iterator.toSeq.head
  }

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[T] = TypeExtractor.getForClass(classOf[T])
}
```

Doing this cause a problem at compilation because T do not seem to be a class :

```
class type required but T found
override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[T] = TypeExtractor.getForClass(classOf[T])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question. I have to use `ClassTag` force type with `asInstanceOf` but it works now :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

import com.sksamuel.avro4s.{AvroInputStream, FromRecord, SchemaFor, ToRecord}
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor

import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect._

class MyGenericAvroDeserializer[T: ClassTag](implicit schema: SchemaFor[T], toRecord: ToRecord[T], fromRecord: FromRecord[T])
  extends DeserializationSchema[T] {

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: T): Boolean = false

  override def deserialize(message: Array[Byte]): T = {
    AvroInputStream.binary[T](new ByteArrayInputStream(message)).iterator.toSeq.head
  }

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[T] =
    TypeExtractor.getForClass(classTag[T].runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[TypeInformation[T]]

}
```

Comment: How is this getting serialized in Flink? I am (de)serializing the exact same way, however this class is not serializable due to (SchemaFor and ToRecord) making it fail at run-time. How did you solve this issue?